# Spring Repository not commit translation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have trouble with spring data jpa repositories.
After executing `save()` method on repository interface data isn't be updated in database. Same situation is with `delete()` and any other query that modifying database.
When I set logging level to DEBUG I can't see any errors and queries other than SELECT.
My application works properly on tomcat 8 on Windows, but when I switched to Linux with the same version of tomcat it doesn't work.

I using the same database on windows and linux.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT**

When I call `saveAndFlush()` on repository I got exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

It looks like I haven't transaction opened, but I have.

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void savePost(Post post) {
    this.postRepository.saveAndFlush(post);
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I tried to deploy this application on Mac OS X and It works.
What's wrong?

**EDIT 3**
Yes, I've enabled spring transaction management by following line:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Comment: If you let the program run, does it eventually save? Operations will not always happen right away. Try saveAndFlush() to force save right after Transaction finishes.

Comment: @DavidR when i call saveAndFlush() i got exception

Comment: Are you using Java on your Linux machine? Linux will generally use OpenJDK and that could have a bug? I'm just taking a guess here.

Comment: I installed java via oracle java installer so this is official java provided by oracle. Should I use OpenJDK?

Comment: Maybe should i try to compile code on linux?

Comment: Maybe try that. I personally wouldn't use OpenJDK. The only thing I can say for sure is it's not a bug in your code.

Comment: I tried to compile on linux, but compiled code doesn't work

Comment: How have you enabled transaction management in your Spring config?

Comment: Yes, I have. Look at my edited post